# How can I use saltstack modules without a master?

Tags: salt-stack

I run a master minion configuration in production but am looking at a master-less configuration.

I can run salt-call --local state.highstate correctly on an isolated machine, but is it possible to utilise CLI modules like this?

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mysql.html

**Edit:**

Heres some debug and log info:

```
root@database-primary:~# salt-call --local mysql.db_exists '##########' -l debug
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: database-primary
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Please install 'virt-what' to improve results of the 'virtual' grain.
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded jinja.render
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded yaml.render
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded jinja.render
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded yaml.render
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad mysql.db_exists
'mysql'' __virtual__ returned False
root@database-primary:~# tail -100 /var/log/salt/minion 
2015-03-22 13:32:52,834 [salt.config      ][DEBUG   ][7319] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
2015-03-22 13:32:52,965 [salt.loaded.int.grains.core][DEBUG   ][7319] Please install 'virt-what' to improve results of the 'virtual' grain.
2015-03-22 13:32:52,990 [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][7319] LazyLoaded jinja.render
2015-03-22 13:32:52,992 [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][7319] LazyLoaded yaml.render
2015-03-22 13:32:52,999 [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][7319] LazyLoaded jinja.render
2015-03-22 13:32:53,000 [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][7319] LazyLoaded yaml.render
2015-03-22 13:32:54,121 [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][7319] Could not LazyLoad mysql.db_exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run all the execution modules without a master. The problem you're running into is it looks like you don't have the required MySQL python modules installed.

Make sure you've installed the python `MySQLdb` module.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run any execution modules you want via `salt-call` in masterless mode (when you pass in `--local` parameter or have `file_client: local` in your minion config)

E.g. if you want to create a db called newdb via mysql module:

```
salt-call --local mysql.db_create 'newdb' 'utf8' 'utf8_general_ci'
```

`state.highstate` just another example of calling execution module, see http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.highstate

Comment: Every command I try returns: "'mysql'' __virtual__ returned False".

I have added the following to my /etc/salt/minion file:

# MYSQL CONFIG
mysql.host: 'localhost'
mysql.port: 3306
mysql.user: 'root'
mysql.pass: '#######'
mysql.db: '#######'
mysql.unix_socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
mysql.charset: 'utf8'